# Sorting with Core Data attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, migrating

I have a `UITableView` that is populated with table view cells from an `NSFetchedResultsController.` Each table view cell is linked to an entity object under Core Data.

I recently performed a lightweight migration and added an attribute that every entity object should have. The problem is, I am not sure how to apply it to the existing table view cells.

To be more specific, I want to add an orderingValue attribute to each object (task) that is linked to a table view cell. How would I make this orderingValue equal to the indexPath.row of the tableviewcell?

Comment: Why don't you add an [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderingValue" ascending:YES] ?

Comment: I did. The problem is some of the objects don't actually have an orderingValue since the objects were created before I added in the orderingValue property. Basically I am asking where in my program I should set the orderingValue property without having any errors